# Assign and execute Javascript function simultaneously

Tags: javascript, function

Is there a more elegant way of writing something like this, where myFunction is asigned to the function func but func is also executed during the assignment?

```
var myFunction = (function(){
  var func = function(){
    console.log('hello world');
  };

  func();
  return func;
})();

...

myFunction();
```

Comment: You could do `return func(), func;`, but I don't think there is a way to avoid the repetition of `func` (unless you return `func` from the function itself). If that's what you are actually talking about. Please clarify which one of those functions you mean.

Comment: Yes I am talking about the repetition of func

Comment: There's nothing wrong with repeating the identifier. They're the thing that lets you tell what is what in code, repeating it makes it *clearer* what's returned and what's executed. Especially if the identifier refers to something like a function that takes up several lines, doing all of this inline would make the code fiddly to mentally parse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var myFunction = (function func(){
  console.log('hello world');

  return func;
})();
```

You can name your anonymous function. This name will only be accessible inside of the function itself, though.

Comment: Now you have a function that returns *itself*. What does that accomplish? (Other than that you can do `myFunction()()()()()()()()()`)

Comment: It is what OP asked for. I dunno, you could chain it like `myFunction()()();`. But that of course could also be accomplished by a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your core statement is this

```
var <name> = (<functionExpression>)();
```

I don't see how this could be more elegant.

Comment: This would assign the return value of the function to the variable.

Comment: @millimoose Yes. Exactly what the OP's code does. Hell, it's an assignment, it assigns the result of an expression (an IIFE in this case) to a variable. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Assignments expressions return the assigned value, but you have to declare the variable separately so you still have to repeat the identifier:

```
var outer;
(outer = function() {
    var inner;
    return (inner = function() {
        print('hello world');
    })(), inner;
})();

outer();
```

That said if I saw this code from a coworker I'd whap him with a rolled up newspaper.